# Install a specific version of angular-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I changed my laptop from windows 7 to windows 10 and i can't install a specific version of the angular cli.

I tried this:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@4.1.0
```

I also tried:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@4.1.0
```

I consistently get:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli@4.1.0"
npm ERR! node v7.9.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0

npm ERR! Cannot read property 'path' of null
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Users\ihazan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-16T13_04_39_665Z-debug.log
```

Node version: 7.9.0

NPM version: 4.2.0

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52067532/2275011 it worked for me

Answer (score 4):

After some investigation, it's actually a stupid error. Nevertheless sharing it as the error message provided above is not clear at all.

It turns out that there is no angular-cli with version 4.1.0.

Re-running with the right version as follows did the trick:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.2.4
```