# How to install Angular-CLI with Angular v4.x

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've installed Angular-CLI using this command

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

but I've realized that it has installed Angular v5.1.3 but I need to use Angular 4.x.

How can I install the last version of Angular-CLI with the last version of Angular 4.x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think downgrade your cli is not good idea becuase they are fixing lots of bug. You can specific your angular in package.json file. don't depend on your cli.

### Edit

First install latest version from your cli. Then Specify the version you want in the 'dependencies' section of your package.json. For example if you want Angular 4.3.4 then you can edit you package.json file like

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.4",
     ...........................
     ...........................
    }
```

Also change your `devDependencies`

```
    "devDependencies": {
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.4",
      "@angular/language-service": "^4.3.4",
      .............
    }
```

and change `package-lock.json`

```
{
.........
  "packages": {
    "": {
............
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.4.4",
        "@angular/common": "^4.4.4",
        "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.4",
        "@angular/core": "^4.4.4",
          .............
        }
```

now run npm install

```
  npm install
```

After finishing install you should see your version by `ng -v` command like this

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 9.3.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: 4.4.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router, tsc-wrapped

@angular/cli: 1.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.38
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.25
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.48
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.3
@schematics/angular: 0.1.13
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.13
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Comment: I tried to use Angular 4 using the following command *ng new angular4test --ng4* using Angular-CLI v1.6.4 but I see this in the package.json file "dependencies": {"@angular/core": "^5.1.0"}. Would you please tell me how to specify the version 4 of Angular?

Comment: @vcRobe I've edited my answer and see how to specify your angular version

Answer (score 10):

you can use

```
 npm i @angular/cli@1.4 -g
```

if you want package JSON file with the versions lower than 5.

> Starting with v1.5 of the Angular CLI, we have added support for Angular v5.0.0 and will generate v5 projects by default.
>   [see link](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced)

Comment: Those who are facing errors in windows while running this command can try using node v12, It worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a simple hack: locally install `@angular/cli@1.4` and use it to generate a new project.

To do that, follow these steps:

1. In a new folder create a simple nodejs project with the command `npm init`
2. Locally install angular-cli 1.4 under this project: `npm install @angular/cli@1.4`
3. Delete the node project files except the newly created `node_modules` folders: this means that you will need to delete `package.json` and any other that it has may be created like `karma.js` etc.
4. Now you can create a new Angular 4 project with the command `ng new <project name>`. It will use the local version of angular-cli previously installed.
5. You may now remove the `node_modules` folder.

Then, if you `cd` in your new project you will have a fully Angular 4 project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

`npm install -g @angular/cli@1.5`

This should install `Angular 4.4.6` and will use `angular-cli 1.5.5`

This was the latest version before 5 came in

Comment: It will install 4.4.6

Answer (score 0):

This means you installed `@angular/cli` globally on your computer so that you can use the `ng` commands from anywhere on a console.

You need to create a new Angular Project using `ng new my-project-name` which will generate all the basic files you need for an Angular project.

In these files, you will find a `package.json` file that contains all the library references you need in your project. It should have the angular package by default at version 5+.

To be 4.X.X like you want, you need to find the best `@angular/cli` version compatible with the Angular version you want (I advise using 1.5.0 or less for `@angular/cli`).

Answer (score 0):

Using `npm install -g @angular/cli` you will install the lastest stable version of the `@angular/cli`.
 So once you create an angular project using the `cli` there will be a `package.json` file, to specify the version of angular to use for the project change the version you would like to use in the package.json file. Then run `npm install`.