# How to install specific version of angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

I am using these commands for installing specific version of angular

```
 [sudo] npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
 npm cache clean -f
 [sudo] npm install -g @angular/cli@1.5.4
```

but these commands are not working didn't get why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Angular-CLI with Angular v4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230917/how-to-install-angular-cli-with-angular-v4-x)