# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular version 5.0.0 or higher error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli-v6

I already had angular project that ran in 4 version. While installing new project, unfortunately i have installed 6 version of angular cli. This throw me an error 'Your global Angular CLI version is greater than your local version' while running ng serve command in old project that ran in 4 version. Again i tried to update my anglar local version. But now i have got an error This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular version 5.0.0 or higher.  My package.json is following:

```
 {
  "name": "authority-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.7.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "angular2-cookie": "^1.2.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.1",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
    "npm": "^5.5.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.22.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^6.1.5",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.44",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

Can someone fix this error. I have been tried from last 2 days, but i cant find any appropriate solution.

Comment: which of the two do you currently have in your projects root, `angular.json` or `angular-cli.json` ?

Comment: I have angular.json

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.
Other answers simply forgot to include the `-g` parameter.

**`npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.9`**

It's all said in the error itself. You're not installing it globally ;)
Hope this solves your issues.

**UPDATE:**
To update Angular CLI to a new version, you must update both the global package and your project's local package.

### **Global package:**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify // If npm version is < 5 then use `npm cache clean`
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

### **Local project package:**

```
// Use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command Prompt; 
// Use rm -r -fo node_modules, dist in Windows PowerShell

rm -rf node_modules dist 
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

For more [info](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/README.md) check out the ReadMe file on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm updating my global and local version of angular cli like you shown above. Now it thrown me error like this: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular"

Comment: That package is newly introduced in Angular 6.0 ... I thought you wanted to work on an Angular 4 project?! :/

Comment: @NabrajBhattarai - Anyways, you could install it as a dev-dependency:  
`npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular` or/ and you can re-run `npm install` in your project.  Additionally, you should check out your NPM version, and might as well update that too if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Use CLI version 1.4.9 with angular 4.

```
npm install @angular/cli@1.4.9

"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    ....
    ....
  }
```

you can refer
[How to install Angular-CLI with Angular v4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230917/how-to-install-angular-cli-with-angular-v4-x)

Comment: Now I have got a message like this: 'Your global Angular CLI version (6.1.5) is greater than your local version (1.4.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.'

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, so I had to check the version of @angular-devkit/build-angular, I run this command:

```
npm list @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

In this way, it can be verified if any additional library such as: **"npx-build-plus"**, is using it and, incidentally, it is updated to the version you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by running:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```