# Angular not working after cloning to a different PC

Tags: node.js, angular

so I got a new pc and I wanted to pass my angular project through github.
I used 1.`npm i` 2.`npm i @angular/cli@latest -D` 3. `ng update`

And Everytime I'm trying to run the project with `ng s` it keeps sending me this error:

```
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^9.0.0-beta || >=9.0.0 <10.0.0,
but Angular version 8.2.14 was found instead.

Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.
https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/
```

I tried using the instructions at the link.

This is my Angular version when typing `ng --version`:

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.1
Node: 12.16.0
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "empire-gaming",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-redux/store": "^10.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.10",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.22",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

I'm really clueless about it... I would be glad if you help me.

Comment: This might be related to this other Stackoverflow question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176881/this-version-of-cli-is-only-compatible-with-angular-version-5-0-0-or-higher-erro

Comment: @vhbazan I used their commands.. still not solving...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The version of Angular that you are using in the project is lower than the version that needed for the latest version of Angular CLI. 
I would recommend you to downgrade the Angular CLI version to 8.3.25

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.3.25
```

And change the version of Angular CLI in your devDependencies:

```
npm install -D @angular/cli@8.3.25
```

Comment: I know that. I'm just keeping updating by so many commands... and it keeps telling me that my version is lower...

Comment: What version of Angular do you see in your package.json?

Comment: I added a package.json to the question.

Comment: so, the version of Angular in your project is 8.2.14 but your CLI needs the 9+ version. Upgrade your Angular version to 9+ or downgrade your Angular CLI version to 8.2

Comment: Where do you see it and how do I update it? I have tried tone of things...

Comment: I'm trying update everthing to lastest version... nothing changes...nothing is updating my version...

Answer (score 5):

First step install Angular globally.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Run Update command to get a list of all dependencies required to be upgraded.

```
ng update
```

Next Run update command as below for each individual Angular core package

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

If you want to force the changes use: `–force` and `–allow-dirty` flags command additionally to fix all other pending issues.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty --force
```

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me

Delete folder **node_modules** and  **package-lock.json**

then execute: "npm install"

---

> in short:

> go to project directory in terminal/command prompt and execute following commands

```
rm -fr ./node_modules
rm -fr ./package-lock.json
npm install
ng serve -o
```

Comment: This would update dependencies which might bring bugs.

Comment: No it will remove existing files and download/create fresh files depends on mentioned dependencies, so file conflicts will be resolved automatically

Comment: I'm not sure if it's fair to downvote this particular answer. It's certainly a fair technique to remove node modules as the local angular cli and other dependencies might still be old stale downloaded versions.

Comment: This is the only thing on the internet that fixed 'ng serve' doing nothing at all, so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but in my experience changing the app package.json file("@angular-devkit/build-angular") to another compatible version works for me :). After the file change, you will be needed to run again these commands "ng update", "npm install" & "ng server"